# How do I check whether I have access to a repository without cloning?

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have some code where people submit git repo links.
The repo may be served over HTTPS with no authentication or HTTPS with basic authentication.
I want to check programmatically whether if I have access to the repo. I don’t want to run `git clone` because it could be time-consuming to download the entire history.   I’m trying to find the fastest way to test authentication.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One route is `git ls-remote` as in

```
$ if git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git.git >/dev/null ; then echo got it ; fi
got it
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

- Use `git init` to initialize a new, scratch git repo.
- Try using `git remote add`, to attempt to add the remote repository.
- Then, attempt a `git remote show`.

If all of these steps succeed, this should be fairly conclusive that you have access to the repository, without doing a full clone.